# Please volunteer for help editing recommendation questions

Tags: discussion, policy, resource-recommendation

Recently, the book policy has been reevaluated, and Manishearth's [proposal](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4698/2751) how to change it seems to be well enough accepted.

What is still missing for the new book policy to become reality, is some people, who are willing to help with editing the new incoming questions and controlling the answers, such that they conform with the needes of the new policy as expl]ained [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4698/2751).

**So please come forward and write a short answer, if you are willing to help with this :-)**

It is not a big job, as the expected average rate of new incoming such questions when allowed again by the new policy, is about one question per two weeks.

Just 2 more people are needed for the policy to succeed.

Comment: I really wonder what horrible sourpusses have to downvote this meta post as well as its answers. Is it just because it is me who has posted it? What is there exactly to _disagree_ about with a post asking people to help with certain tasks on the site? And what is the point in _disagreeing_ with the answers of people who say they are willing to help? So much negativity, hate, and scornfulness is just beyond me. I dont understand this.

Comment: @Manishearth we have now 3 people, all known for hanging around here all the time and being eager editors, who are willing to help with this issue :-). So this should be plenty enough to deal with the expected about 1-2 newly incoming recommendation questions per 2 weeks, such that the new policy can now be realized, no ?

Comment: This question is obsolete, the policy has been effected.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I will try to help; based on my own state of knowledge though.

Comment: This post was automatically flagged as experiencing a "rollback war", so I assume David Z just locked it automatically. Oddly the war seems to have been between Dimension10 and himself which I don't understand unless he was trying to push it into community wiki status. Given that there is no rep on meta that seems silly on top of being abusive.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and unlock it, but I wish to emphasize: editing which seems aimed at forcing CW on a post is abusive.

Comment: Thank you @dmckee.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I am happy to help in the time I have.  Given that my 2 day-to-day jobs are involved in academia and teaching, which include this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am willing to help with editing the recommendation questions and controlling their answers.