# Do we need/want an overarching books question?

Tags: discussion, scope, resource-recommendation

The current tag wiki for the [books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) - now [resource-recommendation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) - tag includes, in its final paragraph, the request that

> If you question is about [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations), please add your question to [the book list](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations) as well.

I just gave that tag wiki a make-over to bring it in line with the [new books policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed/), and I erased that paragraph.

- I think the [books list question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations) is not a good [resource-recommendation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendation) question as per the new policy.
- I don't see that much value in having the question as opposed to simply [looking for questions with that tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations).
- It adds to the curatorial load in dealing with new questions and adds a big backlog to go over.
- It is unreasonable to expect of every asker of resource recommendation questions to edit their question into the big list.

So, there are two things that come to mind:

- Is the [books list question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations) on topic now?
- If so, should we link to it from the tag wiki?

Comment: Actually, I wonder if that sentence should be replaced with one stating something like `If your question is about books, please check the book list to see if your question has been asked and answered already.`

Comment: My tag wiki edits will include a phrase to that effect. They will be visible once they're peer-reviewed.

Comment: I agree with you, but I think should still be kept for historical purposes. Maybe the CW should be removed.

Comment: The overarching books question is a nice way of organizing things in a clean and structured way. I therefore disagree with locking or even deleting it to scatter all the well organized information it contains to tag wikis or wherever...

Comment: Can a new tag be created for the list? I recently saw a user asking a question at physics.SE to recommend him/her list of physics books. It was marked as duplicate, and the book list thread was linked to his post. I have limited options in my mind. Perhaps "library" tag might be useful?

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the book question should be kept and any question on resource recommendations should be automatically linked to it.
It is an extremely useful question as it allows for a person to find books on *any* topic.

Comment: How does that question provide any added value or information over [the tag itself](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations)?

Comment: The proposal that 'any question on resource recommendations should be automatically linked to it' is also not feasible - the main point of [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175) was to provide a curated, indexed look at the tag. Thus each link would need to be added and indexed by a human user. Unless there is a dedicated community that is committed to this (large) workload, this is completely unreasonable.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, I agree with the proposal to get rid of the books question, or at least put a historical lock on it. I would rather have that information in the tag wiki anyway. Not that every resource recommendation should be linked in the tag wiki, but some of the ones on major topics that people are likely to reference frequently.

Comment: A historical lock is ok, but please don't delete, it may contain useful information.