# Why was this answer made community wiki?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, resource-recommendation, community-wiki

This accepted answer I wrote a few hours ago was changed to a community wiki:  [Dynamics and radiation part of Jackson's book - reading advice](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/600662/)

I realize the original question was not a particularly good one, and it is now closed.  Nor am I upset about the 15 reputation.  I am really just curious about why this was done—whether there is a particular reason related to site policy for that kind of answer.

Comment: Why was the original question that you seemed to have answered thoroughly "not a particularly good one"? Was it because it was later closed by the moderator and so suddenly became "not a particularly good one"? If there is some sort of red tape policy on how things are run in a given forum, whether one agrees to it or views it as rather heavy handed, does that mean that the objective original question is at fault?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, this is because there is a convention that all resource-recommendation threads should be made community wiki in their entirety, as agreed on [this thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7041/8563). The reasoning is that the voting pattern on resource-recommendation threads is very different to regular threads, since the votes often follow the quality of the *book* rather than the quality of the *answer*, and there is enormous potential for simple answers generating massive amounts of undeserved reputation. (You may or may not agree with this; this thread is not the place to litigate it.)

... and, with that in place, I would argue that the CW label does not fit this thread (since the reasoning for CW'ing does not apply to it), and by extension neither does the [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) tag nor the accompanying banner. The question deals with books, yes, but it is not asking for recommendations of resources.

As to whether the question is on-topic -- yes, it is a subjective question, but I think it makes the bar in terms of objectivity and should maybe be allowed to remain open. The general standard here comes from the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) SE blog post, and this thread has already shown that it admits answers based on *expertise* that pull together a large body of objective fact into a useful, informative, actionable, verifiable opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Concretely, it was made community wiki because OP added the resource-recommendation tag, cf. the policy from [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7039/2451) meta post.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that your answer was made CW, but that the question was made CW and that automatically converts all answers to CW as well.

As Qmechanic says there is a convention that all resource recommendation questions are CW, and if you tag your question as resource-recommendation it will convert it to CW and as a result convert all answers too.