# What should be done with questions tagged [resource-recommendations] that are not actually asking for recommendations?

Tags: discussion, questions, tags, resource-recommendation, community-wiki

Continuing on from this discussion:  [Why was this answer made community wiki?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13280/)  — about a question that had the [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) tag.

As pointed out in Emilio Pisanty's answer, the main question was not actually asking for a recommendation for a source from which to learn about a topic.  Rather, it was asking about the usefulness of one commonly used resource (Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics*).  Personally, I think it would have made sense to delete the tag, rather than make the question a community wiki—although this might be seen as conflicting with the original questioner's intent.  There is a further question of whether such questions can be on topic at all; the question about Jackson is currently closed, although it does have three reopen votes.

How do we think similar questions should be handled in the future?

Answer (score 5):

If the tag is inappropriate, it should be removed. If the post has already been made community wiki, you can flag it for moderator attention.