# Can I ask for specific books recommendations? using the [resource-recommendations] tag

Tags: discussion, specific-question, resource-recommendation

I researched some question about book recommendations and I found a lot of books on Google Search, and here in physics.se the book recommendation question was closed because it is a broad question, for example, [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/).

**My question is specific: What are the books used nowadays in USA for learning physics in college and university?** (meaning popular books) I am working as a freelance tutor and knowing the material reference from a specific country could improve my services of tutoring.

I had to learn physics for my university and we use Resnick, Serways, Sears & Zemansky. I don’t know if those books are popular in colleges and universities of USA...

Can I ask this here? And if yes, is it a good idea ask for which books are popular by country? Is this question more related to the *[Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tour)* or *[Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Your question isn't specific at all- there are many different popular books used for different fields and for different levels of physics. At a bare minimum you would want to focus on a specific field and level of physics.

Comment: @Chris Fundamentals of Physics In my country is named Physics 1 ( this is kynematics, force, work and energy, momentum, static, gravitation, fluid, gases, circuits )I understand that phy.se use a different terminology for that. I am new here I thought that I know the areas of physics but this SE is another level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, as a general rule, that *geographic* limitations on this type of question are not appropriate here. Asking for what's popular in a specific geographic area will produce results which are only useful to a thin sliver of future visitors, and that's enough to sink that idea.

Resource-recommendation questions are hard to get working correctly, and this site struggled significantly with them some years back, including a full ban on the whole type. The current policy is documented [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed), based on discussions [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/good-list-bad-list/4567#4567) and [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7039/book-recommendations-on-topic-on-topic-but-community-wiki-or-off-topic). Threads that do not follow those guidelines are generally closed.

Regarding other places to ask: this is not really on topic on Academia, and it has as much to do with Open Data as it does with Cooking or Travel. It *could* be on-topic on a (hypothetical) Science Educators SE site, but the various attempts to start one have stalled short of the goal. Unfortunately, just because a question is interesting to someone doesn't mean that there must be an SE site where it can be asked.