# How does community wiki get decided on?

Tags: discussion, questions, resource-recommendation, community-wiki

What are typically the criteria for marking a post as Community Wiki, besides having too many edits? I ask because I had a previous question get labeled as CW; if I understand correctly this label stops the post from being bumped or giving reputation for answers. After this the post was ultimately not answered despite the question being +5 and it seemed like the CW tag was related. I wonder if an early CW-label is preventing some questions from getting answers & I wonder if this is taken into account in the guidelines for when to label something CW.

What reminded me of this was a recent CW label in the following question which I gave an answer for:

[Videos on history of quantum physics or relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/700943/)

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7039/2451

Comment: Thanks for the link. To paraphrase, resource recommendations are seen as either 1. Too easy of a source of reputation for asker + answerer, as they do not involve a derivation or any math or 2. A low-quality post or not necessarily desired on the site but in a gray area which falls under community wiki. My thought on this - FWIW - is that labeling as CW is causing useful questions to get buried despite their value. For concern (1) I would argue that the site is not a perfect meritocracy as it stands, with popular topics winning over others, and (2) I think RRs provide value, so I see no issue.

Comment: That being said, I am just a little drop in the ocean & others' opinions who have seen many more questions than I would be more informed.

Comment: Re *"...criteria for marking a post as Community Wiki, besides having too many edits"*: The too-many-edits rule has [not been in effect since ***2014***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947) - *"We have disabled all forms of* ***community wiki automatic conversions***, *not just for answers but for questions as well."* (my emphasis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) tag automatically converts a question to community wiki, and that's what happened in this case. For more on this see [the tag info](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/resource-recommendations/info) and also [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed).

Comment: While it's true that we *make* every resource-recommendation post CW, this is *not* automatic - a mod has to press the button, just like we have to add the post notice manually. You can see this manual action clearly in [the revision history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/700943/revisions)

Comment: Related: if you happen upon a post that’s tagged resource-recommendation but doesn’t yet have the banner or the community-wiki status (perhaps because you just added the tag yourself), please raise a moderator flag to that effect.