# Should I flag non-CW resource recommendation posts for moderator attention?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderators, resource-recommendation, community-wiki

As far as I know, the current site policy we have is that [resource recommendation questions should be community-wiki](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7039/168783). Also, as far as I know, only moderators can make other people's questions community wiki. Given these, is pointing out resource recommendation questions that are still not CW a fair use of the "moderator attention" flag?

I'm asking because while, as a non-moderator, it seems like a way of helping to identify questions that need to be made CW, if too many users flag those posts then the moderators could be facing some problems with too many flags once a new resource recommendation post comes by (I do not know if flags from different users on the same post for the same reason count as one or many).

Comment: Flags by different users on the same post are grouped together- if they say largely the same thing it's easy to read them all at a glance and handle them with a couple mouse clicks.

Comment: And being overwhelmed with flags is not a likely problem under current conditions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, please flag such posts - there's no guarantee that moderators don't miss these posts otherwise.

In general, please also don't worry about overwhelming us with flags: If you feel something deserves a flag, flag it, that's what flags are for.

Comment: On the subject of "don't worry about overwhelming us": a few years ago one user started some site-cleanup project and generated a bunch of flags. It was not a big deal, but after a few weeks we reached out and said "do you realize you are raising 90% of our community's flags," to which they responded "wow, i had no idea" and eased off without abandoning their project. Really, don't worry about overwhelming us