# Upvote not reflecting in reputation points?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

So I asked a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/730637/book-recommendation-for-blackhole-thermodynamics) and got an upvote on it but it's not reflecting in my reputation. Why is that? Is it a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question has been turned into a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/263383) because it is a resource recommendation question, see [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7039/50583).

Community wiki posts do not grant reputation.