# Does the resource catalogue question still get updated?

Tags: discussion, resource-recommendation

I have been looking at [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations) which is a catalogue of links to resource recommendation questions. For me it has been (in combination with the individual resource recommendations that are linked in the wiki) one of the most useful things on physics.SE. So thank you to the creators! I absolutely love it!!

**I wanted to ask if it is still getting updated?** I've found a few questions that would maybe fit in quite well (although I'm not sure what the criteria are exactly are other than "not too specialised"). Just to give a few of the questions that don't seem to be listed and seem to fit the criteria:

- Maths: [Resources for theory of distributions (generalized functions) for physicists](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127376)
- QFT: [Reading list in topological QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41589)

This meta-question seems related: [Do we need/want an overarching books question?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5307/do-we-need-want-an-overarching-books-question)
I don't want to open a can of worms here, but was there a conclusion/decision about the topic? It doesn't seem to say in the meta-question.

Comment: The two items have now been added to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly add links into the answer there, but I don't think it's a comprehensive list anymore.

The original idea was that only resource recommendation questions of the form "books at [level] about [subject]" would be allowed, where "[subject]" would be one of the big fields like thermodynamics, Newtonian mechanics, quantum field theory, etc. That meant the number of resource recommendation questions would be quite limited, and they could all be listed in one question. But at some point, the community changed its mind in favor of allowing a much broader variety of resource recommendation questions. Given that, it's no longer practical to have a complete list in one place. That's why we haven't really bothered to keep the master recommendation question up to date.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if it's still being updated, the [edit history](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/12176/revisions) will tell you what's been going on there lately. There's some activity there, but really not that much compared to the activity of the tag.

As I've advocated before, the overall books question is of rather limited utility when compared to the site's advanced search features. If you're looking for highly-upvoted questions about topic X in the [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) tag, then [you can simply search for topic X in conjunction with the [resource-recommendations] syntax, and order by votes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=topic+X+%5Bresource-recommendations%5D). It's not immediately as useful as the overarching books question - you do need to adjust your search to what you're looking or browsing for - but with some search-fu you can get a lot of good stuff that way.

In particular, the searches don't get you a curated list of recommendation questions. The reason for this is that there hasn't been enough interest from the community in *curating* such a list. The tag itself takes a fair amount of work to curate (as per the [site policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed/)) and it took ages to bring the old posts in line with the new policy (which I think is mostly done now?). However, there haven't been any volunteers to commit time to the upkeep of that list.

If that were to change, though, I don't think anyone would mind much, at least at the start (particularly provided that the edits to the overarching question are relatively infrequent, so it's not on the front page *all* the time). So if you, or someone else, wants to dig in and make that list answer better - go for it, it's a community project. Just don't complain that the answer is being neglected if you're not personally willing to take charge of its maintenance.