# Why is the following question "on-hold" worthy, and how could I improve it?

Tags: discussion, questions

Link to the question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98637/learning-roadmap-for-picking-up-enough-mathematical-know-how-in-order-to-model

Alternatively, where *could* I go in order to have such a question answered?

Comment: Sites like Quora are usually good with lower level "getting started" questions.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the question is exceedingly broad. We usually deal with specific, conceptual questions here.

Secondly, we just don't do "getting started" questions. A subset of book recommendation questions are allowed, but they need to be reasonably specific too. (See the [meta thread on resource recommendations](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed) to see how to ask one of those.)

So I'm not really sure if it can be fixed while still being useful to you.

You can try asking around in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and thanks for the suggestion too. :)