# Is it ok to ask for recommendations?

Tags: discussion, resource-recommendation

Generally, it is frowned upon on StackExchange to ask for recommendations, unless the site is specifically for that purpose.

Here on Physics, is it ok to ask for recommendations (e.g. for books that cover topics discussed on the site or where one might purchase parts to build devices like a Van de Graff generator and such)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are resource recommendations allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697/)

Comment: Hello mbmast! Please see [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed) that answers precisely this question. In the future, you may wish to search meta before asking, as there may be a duplicate question already in existence.

Comment: I recommend using [the official name of Stack Exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (see the last section).