# What is the site policy on asking for references for concepts?

Tags: discussion, resource-recommendation

Sometimes I find a particular concept which I can't find much description about in the books I know. Is it accepted to ask for references in such scenarios?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable.

Of course, you should make sure that you follow the guidelines given in [Are resource recommendations allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed). To maximize the chances of success of your question:

- provide a description of the concepts that you're interested in with as much detail as you can
- provide a clear picture of what you do and don't understand, so that book recommendations can be given with the correct level of prerequisites
- make sure to look for existing resource-recommendation threads on similar subjects, and if they have a nontrivial overlap with your query, explain why they don't fit your needs