# Can I answer resource recommendation questions by answer them directly?

Tags: discussion, resource-recommendation

For example, question Q care about problem A and need some material about problem A. Can I answer the question by solving problem A directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Resource recommendation questions are for resource recommendations.

Comment: Agreed. Res. rec. questions should not be mixed with physics questions. I'd point out though, that the [faq on res. rec.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697/149907) currently says: *If you see a rather narrow resource recommendation, see if you can convert it into a question about the concept the OP really wants to know, rather than a request for resources that explain the concept. [...] if a resource recommendation looks directly answerable with a reasonable-length answer, then convert it to such a question.*