# Why was my question, on dynamics demonstrations videos, closed?

Tags: support, specific-question

It's a resource request. For questions and comments see:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177194/75644

And if it's not appropriate for this forum then the question is : 
Where on the internet can I hope to get some decent responses to my original question?

Answer (score 3):

I will just recap what has happened so far.

1. A loosely formulated two-line resource recommendation question ([v2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/177194/revisions)) was closed by me. It appeared to be a request for online video lectures, cf. e.g. the answer by Jake Lebovic.
2. Moderators do often leave comments about reasons for closure, but please note that they do not always have the time, as initially in this case.
3. Note that resource recommendation questions are tightly regulated on Phys.SE.
   See e.g. various meta posts [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4561/2451), [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697/2451), and links therein.
4. You later improved the question (v5). This is precisely the right thing to do, so that it enters the reviewing queue. It now became clear that you were *not* looking for online lecture videos. It is then in principle up to the reviewers (3k+ users) to decide the further fate of your question.

Comment: I have to disagree, strongly, with that closure - regardless of how off topic the original version was (which was quite a bit). Closing a question as a duplicate of [Book Recommendations](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/), in general, does *very* little to ensure that the asker will find what they're looking for, and particularly in this case as it does not actually contain any video questions. On top of that, closing as a duplicate of a closed question, which does not relate at all to the topic, [cont.]

Comment: is an excellent way to turn a newcomer away instead of helping them reformulate their question into something useful for the site.  This one could and should have been closed as Too Broad, with a link to the relevant policies; that would have pointed them in the direction of what they needed to do to be on topic. But as it was, this was not handled well at all.

Comment: So is it still in review?

Comment: Who are the reviewers? Can Qmechanic reopen it?

Comment: The links provided by Qmechanic above provide some good general advice, which may be subjectively applied in this case. However, the reasons given by Qmechanic for closing my question don't seem to relate to these principles, as pointed out by Emilio above.

Comment: @ Emilio If by "newcomer" you mean one without the privileges to arbitrarily close questions then yes I am quite put off.

Comment: @pdmclean: at the time of writing your question has four reopen votes (one of them mine :-) and needs just one more to be reopened.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I would say closing something as a duplicate of the general book recommendations question puts viewers two or three clicks away from a huge number of resources that may be useful to them, and so it's much more useful to the OP than closing as too broad. (Not that I would really mind closing as too broad either.)

Comment: Ha! The question got reopened, and someone has now voted to close as *too broad*! :-)

Answer (score 0):

So this was closed again, this time as Too Broad. I disagree with this: the question is perfectly well posed with a concise (and quite demanding) set of requirements on its possible answers. Yes, it could conceivably receive more than one answer, but so do many questions on this site. If it starts receiving a plethora of answers, then we can put them all into a single CW answer (which in fact is probably a good idea anyway).

I can't vote to reopen again but I really disagree with this closure.