# What is the proper way to make a community wiki at physics.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, community-wiki

So I posted this: [A List of Divergent Series and Where they appear in Physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/770025/)

And I want it to be a community wiki not a standard Q&A question.

The process here appears to be done on the answerers side of things: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Can I as a question asker on physics.stackexchange make it into a community wiki? Or would it be acceptable for me to post a question, with an answer myself and then mark it as community wiki for people to update freely?

For more context, the reason I think this is on topic is because i'm not just asking for some calculations but rather I want each divergent series supplied to be from a distinctly DIFFERENT part of physics than all of the previous examples in the list.

This is aggregating a bunch of CONCEPTS together, not just calculations.

I have expressed my view in an [answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14457/) here: [Good list, bad list](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4561/)

Comment: Should we also have lists of which Bessel functions appear where in physics, or where various moments of Gaussians occur? Or is there something special only about divergent series that warrants a list?

Comment: Those lists would certainly be longer but aren’t useless. If someone doing some distant subject such as algebraic geometry ran into a bessel function they might want to see which if any physics/engineering applications might be related to their work. I personally haven’t looked for those topics but I wouldn’t consider them useless. I ask about divergent series because I personally do care about this specific topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Community wiki is described at length on the mother meta, as you've seen. You can make community wiki answers, but the only way to make community wiki questions is to ask a moderator to do so.

Answering your own question is perfectly appropriate. There is really no reason to make it community wiki. Community wiki doesn't make off-topic questions suddenly on-topic.

Currently, your question is closed as off-topic. If you believe it should be on-topic, you should make another meta question asking the community specifically about that.